# Trouble getting pfSense to Authenticate against my Samba4 DC

Tags: samba, authentication, pfsense

Trying to get my pfsense box to authenticate against my Samba4 Active Directory Domain Controller.

- PfSense Version: 2.4.5 (updated today but it wasn't working before the upgrade, either)
- PfSense IP: 10.0.0.1
- Samba version is 4.9.5
- Samba/DNS IP: 10.0.0.2

I've got a user setup in Active Directory: `pfsense` with the group `pfsense-admin` for the "bind credentials" in pfsense.

My authentication server is setup as follows in pfSense:

- Name: pfSense-AD
- Type: LDAP
- Hostname: dc1.example.home `(also tried IP 10.0.0.2, no go)`
- Port Value: 389
- Transport: TCP - Standard
- Peer Certificate Authority: Global Root CA List
- Protocol Version: 3
- Server Timeout: 25
- Search Scope: Level - Entire Subtree, Base DN - DC=example,DC=home
- Authentication Containers: CN=Users,DC=example,DC=home `(also tried CN=Users;DC=example,DC=home, no change)`
- Extended Query: UNCHECKED
- Bind Anonymous: UNCHECKED
- Bind Credentials: CN=pfsense,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=home (with proper password, checked it three times), also tried pfsense@example.home, no change.
- User Naming Attribute: samAccountName
- Group Naming Attribute: cn
- Group member attribute: memberOf
- RFC 2307 Groups: UNCHECKED
- Group Object Class: posixGroup
- UTF8 encode: UNCHECKED
- Username Alterations: UNCHECKED

The pfsense diagnostic test port reports `Port test to host: dc1.example.home Port: 389 successful.`

When I try to test the Authentication in Diagnostics -> Authentication the error is simply:

`The following input errors were detected:
   Authentication failed.`

And the System log shows: `Mar 29 13:28:17  php-fpm     1930    /diag_authentication.php: ERROR! Could not bind to LDAP server pfsense-AD. Please check the bind credentials.`

The samba server is running and Active Directory is working as well - I can connect to the Active Directory via RSAT on Windows 10 Pro and manipulate the Directory. Also tested SSL on the Transport setting and no luck there either.

With the above configuration after about 20 minutes it started working...but now this morning after testing again I get the same error message.

I'm stumped. Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting `ldap server require strong auth = no` in smb.conf. When trying to use ldapsearch from command line of pfsense I kept getting

`ldap_bind: Strong(er) authentication required (8)
additional info: BindSimple: Transport encryption required.`

When I knee 100% all my information was correct. An email list thread on samba.org pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

after many research on this issue i realized that the option of pfsense already exists
do not disable "ldap server require strong auth = no"

in pfsense 2.4.5
you need to change the transport option
with tcp-starttls
with any certificate

for me it works